# Scala on Heroku, foreman start, Procfile does not exist

Tags: scala, heroku, foreman, procfile

I am following the Scala on Heroku tutorial: 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-scala#store-your-app-in-git.
When I try to build the application locally by typing:
**foreman start**,
I get and error:
**Procfile does not exist**.
But it does!!
Procfile contains:
**web: target/start Web**,
and when I type in:
**target/start Web**,
the app runs locally no problem...
I also successfully deployed the application to Heroku so it looks like there is nothing wrong with the Procfile, somehow Foreman doesnt see the file... Any ideas why?

Comment: I know this sounds silly but if the file by any chance has a lowercase `p` instead of an uppercase, this can happen.